# Turkish Currency Symbol is being displayed as square

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization

I have a asp.net mvc application which stores currency types in the database. Symbol for each currency is also stored in the db. Currency types are retrieved from the db and currency symbols are displayed in a dropdown in my application.

In my development machine all of the currency symbols are displayed properly in the dropdown. But in the production machine, turkish currency symbol is displayed as a square for the same dropdown. Both environments have the same symbol in the db. And this symbol is retrived from database and presented without any modifications all the way to the browser.

My development machine is set to United States format, production machine is set to Swedish format. So I initially thought the problem was because of that, but when I change the system format to swedish in my dev machine, I couldn't reproduce the problem.

Another difference between the environments is the .net version, they are slightly different, but it is less likely to be the root cause of the issue.

I am running out of ideas, can somebody guide me the right direction?

Comment: It's likely a font issue.  You are using a font that includes the symbol and the other machine doesn't have that font and the font it defaults to doesn't include that symbol.

Comment: Does the production machine display the symbol correctly in other contexts? Like when reading the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_lira_sign), or my comment: ₺₺₺

Comment: @Quantic that's a great idea, I opened up your comment in the production machine, turkish currency symbol is displayed as squares. so does that mean IE is not able to display turkish currency symbol?

Comment: @juharr so as a solution, I need to add a font that includes turkish currency symbol to the production machine?

Comment: Maybe try the things listed [here](http://superuser.com/questions/336197/unicode-characters-suddenly-start-displaying-as-boxes-in-some-applications). It's not a font issue, that symbol exists as a unicode character separate from what font you decide to display that character with.

Comment: thanks @Quantic, I don't have admin rights in the production server, but I will try first thing when I talk to the system admin